# How do I upload a base64 encoded file contained in javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, upload

I am working with a browser plugin that receives input from a scanner and returns a base64 encoded string.  I'm trying to take this string and use it as the content of a form post.  I'm at a loss.

```
var formElem = document.getElementById("fileUploadForm");
var imagedata;

Plugin.SelectedImagesCount = 1;
Plugin.SetSelectedImageIndex(0,0); // Set the 1st image as the first selected image.

Plugin.GetSelectedImagesSize(1); //jpeg
imagedata = Plugin.SaveSelectedImagesToBase64Binary();
//This is where I'd like to send the imagedata to the server
```

I've tried searching, but the only method I've found so far is constructing custom http to emulate a form submission.  I would like to reuse the existing form that I have for file uploads.

```
<form id="fileUploadForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Scanning -->
    <select name="docType">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <button onClick="ScanImage(); return false;">Scan</button>
    <!-- Uploading -->
    <input id="DocUploadInput" type="file" name="RemoteFile" />
    <button onClick="fileUpload(this.form,'/UploadDocument/'); return false;">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it possible to send it to the server as a string and decode it there?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, but I was hoping to reuse the form that I already have for sending files.